# Logging extra information in asynchronous programming

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, logging

*Despite example below is written on Python, it's not so python-dependent.*

I need to pass extra per-request information every time like client-id for every single log item including ORM without modification of every library and application we use.

With synchronous programming, like you can see in example below, it's easy as we can create extra to pass and modify this extra one time per each request. But what to do in asynchronous programming as this technique becomes useless?

The sample code here is written on `Python` as it's easiest way to illustrate problem here but question itself is language-independent.

Logger configuration file:

```
# logging_config.py

extra = {
   'application': None,
   'client_id': None 
}

# use custom logstash formatter to send this extra
```

Our main application file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import logging
import our_lib.logging_config as log_cfg


log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def application_setup():
   """ Sets up application and logging. """
   log_cfg['application'] = 'OurWebApplication'
   ...  # do the rest here
```

Our request processor:

```
# api_handler.py
import logging


log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


...  # rest of the file


def extract_client_id(request):
    """ Extracts Client ID from request or session. """
    ...


# some web API request handle
@route('/api/do_smth')
def api_do_smth_handler(request):
    """ Handles `do_smth` web request. """

    log_cfg.extra['client_id'] = extract_client_id(request)
    ...
```

Some library module:

```
import logging


log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def process_data(*args, **kwargs):
    """ Processes arguments. """

    try:
        ...  # process arguments
    except MyException:
        log.exception("argument processing failed")  # <-- how to log client ID here?
```

Comment: I don't see how this would be that different in an async environment.  Is it because extract_client_id  is also an async call?  This is easily handled in node/express using the middleware. It seems like it is just as easily handled in an async python environment using something similar.

Comment: The difference will be in execution flow, not in the logic.

Comment: just for example, if we preserve this logic and one request starts in the middle of another request (this is true for asynchronous programming itself), we'll log wrong data.

Comment: Eevery high level async framwork is going to give you access to a stable request all through the request/response cycle.  Again look at some of the node docs.  You are worried about a non-existent problem.

Comment: I need to add extra to all ORM logs as well as logs from other custom libraries